# Proof e is irrational — Choice of Sign of m/n = e and Uncanny Step

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, proof-explanation

[Assume $e$ is rational](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Number_is_Irrational). Then, there exist coprime integers $m$ and $n$, and we can choose $n$ to be positive, such that: $\displaystyle \frac m n = e = \sum_{i \mathop = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {i!}$ from the definition of [[Definition:Euler's Number/Limit of Series|Euler's number]].

Multiplying the previous infinite series for $e$ by $n!$ $\color{red}{(1) \text{Why do this — eliminate the denominators? Please edit this if wrong}}$:

$ \begin{align} n! \frac m n & = n! \sum_{i \mathop = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {i!} 
\\ & = \left({\frac{n!}{0!} + \frac{n!}{1!} + \frac{n!}{2!} + \cdots + \frac {n!}{n!}}\right) + \color{blue}{\left({\frac{n!}{\left({n + 1}\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left({n + 2}\right)!} + \frac{n!}{\left({n + 3}\right)!} + \cdots}\right)} \end{align}$

$\color{green}{m\left({n - 1}\right)! - \left(\frac{n!}{0!} + \frac{n!}{1!} + \frac{n!}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{n!}{n!}\right)} $
     $\begin{align} =\color{blue}{\frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 2}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 2}\right) \left({n + 3}\right)} + \cdots} (*) \\   
      < \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right)} + \frac 1 {\left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right) \left({n + 1}\right)} + \cdots \\
      =\sum_{i \mathop = 0}^\infty \left ({\frac 1 {n+1} }\right)^{\left({i + 1}\right)}
      =\frac{\frac 1 {n+1} } {1 - \frac 1 {n+1} }  = \frac 1 n \\ & \color{magenta}{< 1} \end{align}$
from [[Sum of Infinite Geometric Progression]]

Observe that $\color{green}{green}$ must be an integer, as it is composed entirely of sums and differences of integral components. Because $0 <$ RHS of $(*)$ and of the paragraph overhead,  thence  $0 < \color{green}{green} \color{magenta}{<1} $, a contradiction because no integers exist in $(0, 1)$.

**(2)** What ratifies the right to choose $n > 0$? Rational numbers can $< 0$ so $m$,$n$ can $< 0$?

**(3)** Purport that we aren't working with $2.7 < e < 2.8$. Instead we are working with another variable and don't know its sign — after letting $x = m/n$, then what are the the signs of $m, n$?

**(4)** The key comes off as isolating the blue sum  and moving $\left({\frac{n!}{0!}  + \cdots + \frac {n!}{n!}}\right)$ to the left
— later proving  $\color{green}{green} < 1$? How can you prefigure this uncanny step?

Comment: I've removed the messy cut-and-paste from ProofWiki.  Quoting another source is good, but if you can't format it properly then just leave a link.

Comment: @Goos http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12354/what-went-astray-in-this-code-based-on-proofwiki-but-i-tried-to-edit/12357?noredirect=1#comment48383_12357 achilles.hui fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

1. ANY rational number can be written as $\frac{m}{n}$ with $n>0$. For example, $\dfrac{5}{-2}$ can also be written as $\dfrac{-5}{2}$. Just flip the sign.
2. We don't need to know the sign of $m$. We do in fact need to know $n>0$ since we are using $n!$ which is only defined for nonnegative integers.
3. One thing to notice is that the series converge (to $n!e$) so it's always possible to cut off after a certain point so that the remaining terms sum up to less than 1. The point here is that you do not want that point to be too far, because you want the partial sum to be still an integer. Luckily, it works because the series drop off very fast; the same technique would work for any similarly fast dropping series.

Comment: thanks gina. Can you please answer (1)? It didn't have a number before. And can you clarify your answer to my (4). 'Because you want the partial sum to be still an integer'. Which partial sum do you mean? And what do you mean 'the series drops off very fast'? And why did you write 'the series converges to $n!e$? Isn't it equal to $n!e$?

Comment: Dear Dwayne, (a) "converges to" is another way of expressing "equals to" in the context of a series.  (In some sense, the series exists whether or not the corresponding sequence of partial sums has a limit; if this limit exists, then that limit is defined to be the values, or sum, of the series, and so we often then say that the series *converges* to this value, as a shorthand for saying that the sequence of partial sums converges to this value.)  (b) There is only one partial sum in the argument, namely the sum of the first $n$ terms, so this is the partial sum Gina is referring to. ...

Comment: Note that if you took an earlier partial sum, then the remainder would be $>1$, while if you took a larger partial sum, its value would not obviously be an integer.  (c) The terms in the series $\to 0$ very rapidly; this is what Gina means by "the series drops off very fast".  (d) Note also that pretty obviously the value of $e$ is $> 0$, since it is the sum of a series with positive terms, so if it is a rational number, it is a positive rational number, and so can be written as a ratio $m/n$ where $m,n  > 0$.  (Although as Gina notes, you don't actually need to use this.) Regards,

Comment: P.S.  Your question (1) is basically the heart of the proof; this is the trick.  Obviously you want to clear denominators in some way: it is hard to recognize whether or not a real number is rational, but easy to recognize whether or not it is an integer, so it is natural to convert the question to one involving integers.  The idea of doing it by multiplying by $n^!$ (and say not just $n$) is the trick at the heart of the argument.

Comment: @MattE thanks. do you want to answer with these comments?

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be about pedagogy (motivation) rather than about mathematical content. The proof below adds no mathematical ideas to the original question and answer, but may seem more natural (several small bites) than the argument in the question (one big bite).

Suppose you're interested in investigating (estimating numerically, determining (ir)rationality of) the sum
$$
e = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}.
$$
Fix an arbitrary positive integer $q$. It's straightforward to establish that $q!(q+1)^{j} \leq (q+j)!$ for all $j \geq 1$ (with equality if and only if $j = 1$), so we can split the sum and use a geometric series to estimate the tail:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!} + \sum_{i=q+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}
  &= \sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!} + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(q+j)!} \\
  &< \sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!} + \frac{1}{q!} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(q+1)^j} \\
  &= \left(\sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!}\right) + \frac{1}{q \cdot q!}.
\end{align*}
In particular, for *every* positive $q$ we have the estimate
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!}
  < e
  < \left(\sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!}\right) + \frac{1}{q \cdot q!}.
$$

Taking $q = 2$, we find that $2.5 < e < 2.75$. Particularly, $e > 0$ and $e$ is not an integer.

It's also natural to note that each term in the sum is a fraction whose denominator divides $q!$, so multiplying the preceding inequality by $q!$ clears the denominators:
$$
q! \sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!}
  < q!\, e
  < \left(q! \sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!}\right) + \frac{1}{q}
  \leq \left(q! \sum_{i=0}^{q} \frac{1}{i!}\right) + 1.
\tag{1}
$$
Again, (1) holds *for every positive integer $q$*, solely by virtue of the definition of $e$.

Now we're ready to tackle irrationality. Since $e > 0$, if $e$ is rational, there exist *positive, coprime* integers $m$ and $n$ such that $e = m/n$. Since $e$ is not an integer, $n > 1$. Introduce the integers
$$
N = n! \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{1}{i!},\qquad
M = n!\, e = m(n - 1)!.
$$

By the estimate (1) with $q = n$, we have $N < M < N + 1$. Contrapositively, since no such integers exist, there do not exist positive, coprime integers $m$ and $n$ such that $e = m/n$; that is, $e$ is irrational.

To address items (2) and (3) in the original question: Every rational number may be written in the form $m/n$ with $n > 0$ because $m/(-n) = (-m)/n$. Thus, regardless of the sign of the rational number $m/n$, there is no loss of generality in taking $n$ to be positive.

Comment: thanks, but your proof looks harder than the one in my question? thence how does it answer my questions (1) and (4)?

Comment: @DwayneE.Pouiller: Your original proof was brief but (according to your question) opaque and unmotivated. If the proof I posted makes sense, you should now be able to see why one would think to (1) clear the denominators and (4) prove that the green terms sum to less than $1$.